# Map values from one data frame to another based on position

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have following 2 data frames-

**1st Data frame looks like this:**

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4)
a <- c(1,1,0,1)
b <- as.character(c(0,1,1,1))
c <- as.character(c(0,1,1,0))
d <- c(0,1,1,0)
dt <- data.frame(id,a,b,c,d, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> dt
  id a b c d
1  1 1 0 0 0
2  2 1 1 1 1
3  3 0 1 1 1
4  4 1 1 0 0
```

**2nd Data frame looks like this:**

```
id <- c(1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
col <- c("a","a","b","c","d","b","c","d","a","b")
val <- as.character(c("t1","x1","x2","x3","x4","y2","y3","y4","z1","z2"))
values <- data.frame(id,col,val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> values
   id col val
1   1   a  t1
2   2   a  x1
3   2   b  x2
4   2   c  x3
5   2   d  x4
6   3   b  y2
7   3   c  y3
8   3   d  y4
9   4   a  z1
10  4   b  z2
```

I am trying to map values of col column in 2nd data frame to replace 1 in data frame 1.

Please look at desired output below:

```
> output
   id  a  b  c  d
1:  1 t1  0  0  0
2:  2 x1 x2 x3 x4
3:  3  0 y2 y3 y4
4:  4 z1 z2  0  0
```

**My Attempts:**

I know this can be accomplished by directly dcasting **value** dataframe but I face long vector issue. Intead I am using `sparseMatrix()` to get dataframe 1 and then I can map original values from dataframe 1.

NOTE- I have a very large data and I can't use `data.table::dcast.data.table()`

Suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Comment: So your real data sets are sparse matrices? Also, it's not clear why can't you use `dcast`? Speed? Out of memory? What does "*face long vector issue*" mean?

Comment: @David Arenburg So I am getting long vector error while using dcast() function and to avoid that I am using sparseMatrix(). But, sparseMatrix doesn’t support character value in its x parameter.

Comment: How many rows and columns does you production dataset have (in wide format)? What is the share of zeros in wide format?

Comment: @Uwe I have approx 14k columns wide and more than 1 billion rows. I have approx 60-70% 0's.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Error: long vectors not supported yet